# How to do binary search and print our resulting index array

Tags: python

My code is not working. I am not good at code and I am sorry for wasting your time. I have never been good at this and I am trying to understand how to do linear and binary searches. I hope you can fix my problem as this just doesn't make sense and I'm sorry if I seem stupid.

I want to print the result of where the item is in the array, I cannot, how would I do this?

I have created a function and with this I was able to get the main binary function working, but I want it to print the index.

Here is my code:

```
def binary_search(array,item):
    start_point = 0
    end_point = len(array)
    mid_point = (start_point + end_point) / 2
    while mid_point != item:
        if mid_point > item:
            end_point = mid_point
        elif mid_point < item:
            start_point = mid_point
    if mid_point == item:
        print(mid_point)

binary_search([0,3,5,6,7,8],7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has an inbuilt function of getting index of a particular item from a list i.e. **list.index(element)**

```
>>>k = [3,4,5,7]
>>>k.index(7)
>>>3
```

Comment: i know,, but i'm looking for a way to actually show the steps of binary search, ur help is appreciated though

Comment: Thanks, if you can be a little bit more specific, I can update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic error for list.
When comparing with item, it should be:
    array[mid_point] != item
It will be better if you learned about data structure first before trying to deal with algorithms.